# script to replace href http:// with //

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, bigcommerce

The e-commerce platform I use, bigcommerce, uses global variables to insert data dynamically. I don't have access to the php needed to manipulate the variables server side.

Unless at checkout, the variables all render http: links, I'd like a script to make them relative so if someone wants to browse via https: all of the menu and category links will comply.

I'm currently use this to correct my main nav but it is obviously not a best case solution, and the remainder of the generated links remain http

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    relativeLinking();
    function relativeLinking(){
        var GLOBAL_PagePath = "%%GLOBAL_PageLink%%".substring(5);
        document.getElementById("%%GLOBAL_PageName%%").setAttribute("href", GLOBAL_PagePath);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain how you have a platform without access to the server side bit?

Comment: it is hosted on servers owned by provider, i can only manipulate on the front-end

Comment: SO "My e-commerce platform, bigcommerce," is factually incorrect. It is not yours.

Comment: then pardon my semantic error. The platform I use to host my storefront. I hope you still understood my question... don't see how that's relevant

Comment: A criminal with an ounce of sense will discover that your site is still available through `http` - not `https` and hence you site is insure.

Comment: ed i don't believe you understand the nature of my inquiry. all i want to do is provide links relative to the protocol they prefer. all sensitive content is forced ssl. but thanks for your input

Comment: Just deliver it in the correct protocol in the first place. Simpler - Safer. How about you make a slip up?

Comment: ah, you must not have read my question. the links are provided via variables from the backend. they are hardcoded with http: where https: is not overtly needed...

Answer (score 2):

you can tranform all links using this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.attr('href', self.attr('href').replace(/.*\/\//,'//'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dustin,

This Javascript code

```
    var GLOBAL_PagePath = "%%GLOBAL_PageLink%%".substring(5);
    document.getElementById("%%GLOBAL_PageName%%").setAttribute("href", GLOBAL_PagePath);
```

sets the attributes. Why require this and not just deliver the correct HTML in the first place.

One assumes that needing this that the web master does not know (or care?) the HTML/PHP/JS etc on the two sites (http:// and https:// protocol).

Certain files should be on one site and nor the other. Vice - Versa.

Comment: if you would read my question, the html in question is generated via a variable from the backend. it outputs "http://..." and i'd simply like to make them relative. i believe i also made this clear in response your previous comments. i believe that you don't understand the nature of my question or circumstances